# installing a django_url_alias module

Tags: django, alias, django-urls

I have a requirement of creating a external URI which is different from internal URI. External URI will be configured/created by Website user and Internal URI will be created on the fly by Application itself.

Module django_url_alias perfectly fits in my requirement. I have followed the process of installation as mentioned in the Readme file.

https://github.com/ddanier/django_url_alias#installation

however when i am trying to access the home page, I am getting following error :

**AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'**

after toubleshooting i think it is because i have not followed below step:
Replace settings.ROOT_URLCONF with "django_url_alias.urls"

Since it is still referring to ROOT_URLCONF instead of django_url_alias.urls.

Please help by suggesting how to make above mentioned change.
Thanks in advance.

made changes to settings.py as below :

```
'# ROOT_URLCONF = 'TestApp.urls''
```

```
'URL_ALIAS_MODULES = URLAliasModule'
```

```
'URL_ALIAS_ROOT_URLCONF = 'TestApp.urls''
```

and following in the template.html file :

```
`{% load url_alias %}`
```